# How does a computer "know" that it is being turned on?

Tags: boot

I'm trying to figure out how can a physical device like a computer detect that it's been just turned on in order to initiate a boot process. I can imagine a computer "waking up" and, while totally unaware that it was "dead", say to itself *"well I see there is some electrical current through me, and **something** is telling me to invoke these specific set of instructions"...*

What is that **something**, and how does it work? It looks very mysterious to me. Please note that the web contains many high-level boot process explanations (a fairly detailed one is [here](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-computers-boot-up/)). What I'm wondering about is the primordial detection/discovery process that sparkles everything that comes after it.

Comment: It knows because it passed it's short for power-on self-test (POST) and modern computers now expect a bootable device after that happens..

Comment: @Ramhound does the POST execute continuously after being "energized"? Turn it into a full answer so it can be properly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What does your research indicate?  My comment isn't worthy of being an answer.  I would appreciate it, if nobody made it into one though, I will not appreciate any answer that copies my statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Computers have hardware that detects the application of power and triggers a reset process to put the computer into a known state, the one from which the boot process follows.

You can think of it like a bucket with a very slow leak that is filled from a faucet. When the faucet is off, the bucket is empty. When the faucet turns on, the bucket is *still* empty. After a period of time, the bucket is full and it stays full so long as the faucet is on. When the faucet is turned off, the bucket gradually empties, ready to repeat the process.

Except, in a computer, the bucket is a capacitor and the leak is a resistor. The capacitor gradually charges through another resistor when power is applied, but until it does, the voltage across the capacitor remains low enough to trigger a reset. A traditional reset button shorts out the capacitor, equivalent to dumping out the bucket.

Simple computers typically have CPUs that are designed to begin executing from a known address when they get a reset signal. The software at this address puts the hardware into a known state and does whatever the appropriate next step is such as loading the OS. The process is a bit more complex in a PC.

Comment: Seems implicit in what you wrote, but a PC (read: motherboard circuitry) is *always on* and energized when the computer is plugged in to an energized socket (and the PSU switch is "on" if so equipped), right? Presumably on battery power as well.

Comment: @Yorik You can argue that there really are two "reset" processes, one that applies when power is initially applied (but we still think of the machine as off) and one when we turn it on, transitioning from a standby state to an active one.

Comment: A highly digestible answer for someone totally non-electronics-oriented like me.